# Why fileWriter is witten in the output file before bufferedWrite and printWriter?

Tags: java, file, writer

I'm trying some Java.io classes such as **File**, **FileWriter**, **BufferedWriter** and **PrintWriter**.

I didn't understand why FileWrite `.write()` methods are always printed before all the others bufferedWriter and printWriter's `.write()` and/or `.println()` methods.

```
try(FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("file.res");
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter)){

            bufferedWriter.write("BufferedReader\n");

            printWriter.println("PrintWriter");

            fileWriter.write("FileWriter\n");

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

produces as output:

```
FileWriter
BufferedReader
PrintWriter
```

Is it normal? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is.

`FileWriter` is not buffered, so writing to it writes immeditately to disk.

`BufferedWriter` writes first to a buffer (in memory). The `PrintWriter` itself is not buffered, so it writes immediately to the underlying  `BufferedWriter` and therefore writes to memory too. For these two, the order of write operations is kept, because they are written in the same order to memory.

When the `try-with-resources` block is finished, the resources (Writers) are implicitly closed. Before being closed, the flush method of the writer is invoked, causing the contents of the buffer to be written to the underlying writer - the `FileWriter` - and therefore to disk.

So the order of execution is

```
bufferedWriter.write("BufferedReader\n"); -> buf[0..n]
printWriter.println("PrintWriter"); -> buf[n+1...m]
fileWriter.write("FileWriter\n"); -> file[0..a]

//implicit close
bufferdWriter.close(); buf[0..m] -> file[a+1..a+m]
```

And the file result will look like

```
file[0..a,a+1..a+n,a+n+1..a+m]
     ^  ^ ^      ^ ^        ^
     |FW| | BW   | |   PW   |
```